# Erro ao fazer upload com FireBaseStorage.net com Xamarin

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin-forms, firebase-database

Desenvolvi a seguinte rotina para fazer upload de imagens.

```
         var task = new FirebaseStorage("xxxxxx.appspot.com")
             .Child("data")
             .Child("random")
             .Child("file.png")
             .PutAsync(img);
```

Quando tento enviar recebo a seguinte mensagem :

```
Exception occured while processing the request.
Url: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/xxxxxxx.appspot.com/o?name=data%2Frandom%2Ffile.png
Response: N/A
```